# Ubuntu 12.04 vhost page not found

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, domain-name-system

I am running `Ubuntu 12.04 LTS` server. 
On that server I have installed `iRedAdmin` as my mail server. So far so good. Now I want to add my company's website to this server, but i can't get it to work.
I have pointed DNS records to my server **[vpl.si](http://vpl.si)** and added `vhost` file to 
 `sites-avaliable`. After that, I did `a2ensite vpl.si` and `sudo service apache2 reload`.

Also, permission for www folder is set to `chomd -R 777 /www`.

My vhost file for `vpl.si` looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost vpl.si:80>
    ServerAdmin postmaster@vpl.si
    ServerName vpl.si
    ServerAlias www.vpl.si  
    DocumentRoot /var/www/
    <Directory /var/www/ >
        Options None
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

But I still get page not found. I have no idead what I am doing wrong?
Thanks!

**EDIT**: `I forgot to add Allow 80 to UFW Firewall. It is working now.`

Comment: Ok, so I guess that page not found wasn't the real error message you received

Comment: It was what Chrome showed me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to remove domain name

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin postmaster@vpl.si
    ServerName vpl.si
    ServerAlias www.vpl.si  
    DocumentRoot /var/www/
    <Directory /var/www/ >
        Options None
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: still not working =/

Comment: have you try ping your domain name? make sure it was pointed to your host

Comment: yes, still nothing

Comment: is it online? or local site?

Comment: it's online, but not working

Comment: i just try ping it. it is timeout.

Comment: weird, it's working for me..

Answer (score 0):

The only things I see in the info provided that's odd is you have DocumentRoot set to /var/www but you then say you chmod /www so if that's correct, perhaps you need to set DocumentRoot to /www.

As an aside it's unnecessary to ever chmod 777 your web tree.

Comment: It is still not working. Even if i disable vpl.si and enable default index.html in default directory is not showing up.. Anything else I could try?